# How to implement existing word2vector into EmbedID?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, chainer

I know the way to initialize the **`EmbedID`** randomly. But now I want to load existing **`w2v`**, like the **`Glove`**, and update it constantly with the training process. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And I want to update it constantly with the training process.

Comment: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.train_cbow_pair

Comment: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.train_sg_pair

Comment: I didn't try to relearn the wor2vec. But this two functions is used internally by word2vec class for training.